# Android ImageView Anchor image to side

Tags: android

Is there a way to force the image to anchor to the left or right side no matter what the size of ImageView is? Every time I change the size of the ImageView, the image seems to center itself to the ImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html). You'll want to add android:gravity="right" to your ImageView.